# In right-to-left language(like Arabic and Hebrew),bracket reversed

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

Now I have a string like (in ltr)

> Hebrew text(3)

and when I use dir="rtl" or direction:rtl to redirect the string it actually goes:

> מחיר אחד(3)

(actually i entered Hebrew charactor(3) just now it automaticlly became like above↑)

is there any way to make it like

> (3)Hebrew text

(using html or css)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to wrap the bracketed text in a separate span.

Rather, to fix this problem add a **RLM control character** (`&rlm;`) after the closing bracket. The RLM character acts as another Hebrew/Arabic character and so the bracket ( which is a weak character) changes its direction and moves to its correct place.

Like so:

```
<div>מחיר אחד(3)&rlm;</div>
```

**NB:** If you set the attribute `dir="rtl"` on the element - then even the RLM control character is unnecessary.

Like so:

```
<div dir="rtl">מחיר אחד(3)</div>
```

**[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/eqduI)** (jsFiddle down by me)

This [microsoft doc](http://www.microsoft.com/middleeast/msdn/control.aspx) explains the RLM control character along with other similar control characters.

Comment: I found my example in the article not very appropriate~you r right in your second line of codes,when i use dir='rtl' and thansk to browser everything goes well(i remember when i set up this question it messed up...is this my illusion or chrome updated..?)

Comment: anyway my problem has been solved.But i think out a new condition that when i use a hebrew phrase in english(ltr) or an english phrase in hebrew(rtl) with brackets,it will also messes up.In the case if we dont wanna waste a span to wrap and style the specific language phrase we can use `&rlm;` or `&lrm;`.

Answer (score 6):

(updated: thank you rob for clarifying your comment)

this is a little less invasive solution ([result in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaakkytt/67SCT/)):

```
<span lang="he" dir="rtl">מחיר אחד<span>(3)</span></span>
```

It seems the last parentheses is concidered as punctuation and thus treated differently. [This article](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/web/tips/align.html) gave me some clarity:

> ... Note that unlike align="right", the punctuation will also relocated... See [Sample RTL Document](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/web/tips/alignrtl.html)

In the sample document the same relocation of the last parentheses also occurs within the subtitle "Bidirectional Override (BDO)".

*checked the jsfiddle solution in latest chrome/ff/safari/ie

Comment: Are you aware if the solution you supply is a known bug you are working around or your solution is the correct way to deal with the expected browser behaviour? What browsers did you test your solution in ?

Comment: Since I am not familiar with rlt languages and thus with their browser specifics I can't be 100% sure if my solution is the absolute correct way for dealing with the given situation but if the parentheses are concidered as punctuation and as such a subject for relocation, a span wrapper seems to cancel that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

one of the solutions is to add `**&#x200e;**` after the bracket

thanks to @freeworlder for the solution on brackets displays wrongly for right to left display style

even you can use other char, follow this link http://www.codetable.net/hex/200e